# Show that the modified Pell equation $x^2 - 7y^2 = -1$ has no solutions in integers $x,y$.

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, diophantine-equations

Show that the modified Pell equation $x^2 - 7y^2 = -1$ has no solutions in integers $x,y$. (Hint: reduce the equation modulo a suitably chosen prime.)

I think that we can use the Diophantine equation for this, but I don't know where to start. I am new to this material in Number Theory.

Comment: Hint: Can you see a prime in $x^2-7 y^2$?

Comment: $x^2 \equiv -1 \bmod p$ and $(-1)^{(p-1)/2}$

Comment: Also, $$\sqrt{7}=[2,\underbrace{\overline{1,1,1,4}}_{\text{even length}}].$$

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Add $8y^2+4$ to both sides of the equation getting $x^2+y^2+4 = 8y^2+3$
Now read this equation modulo 4, we get $x^2+y^2\equiv3\pmod 4$. As any square leaves a remainder of 0 or 1 mod 4, adding two of them (the LHS) we cannot get 3 (the RHS).

Comment: Thank you, the hint given to us was to reduce the equation modulo to a prime. I appreciate your help!

Answer (score 3):

Take both sides modulo 7. We have $x^2=-1$ modulo 7 which has no solution as 7 is a prime of type 3 mod 4.

Answer (score 2):

Try lifting all the solutions modulo $7$.

Answer (score 1):

$$  \sqrt { 7} = 2 +     \frac{  \sqrt {7} - 2 }{ 1 }  $$ 
 $$    \frac{ 1 }{   \sqrt {7} - 2 }  =  \frac{    \sqrt {7} + 2 }{3 } = 1 +  \frac{    \sqrt {7} - 1 }{3 } $$ 
 $$    \frac{ 3 }{   \sqrt {7} - 1 }  =  \frac{    \sqrt {7} + 1 }{2 } = 1 +  \frac{    \sqrt {7} - 1 }{2 } $$ 
 $$    \frac{ 2 }{   \sqrt {7} - 1 }  =  \frac{    \sqrt {7} + 1 }{3 } = 1 +  \frac{    \sqrt {7} - 2 }{3 } $$ 
 $$    \frac{ 3 }{   \sqrt {7} - 2 }  =  \frac{    \sqrt {7} + 2 }{1 } = 4 +  \frac{    \sqrt {7} - 2 }{1 } $$

Simple continued fraction tableau:
 $$ 
 \begin{array}{cccccccccccccc}
 & & 2 & & 1 & & 1 & & 1 & & 4 & \\ 
 \\ 
  \frac{ 0 }{ 1 }   &   \frac{ 1 }{ 0 }   & &   \frac{ 2 }{ 1 }   & &   \frac{ 3 }{ 1 }   & &   \frac{ 5 }{ 2 }   & &   \frac{ 8 }{ 3 }    \\ 
  \\ 
 & 1 & & -3 & & 2 & & -3 & & 1
 \end{array}
 $$

$$ 
 \begin{array}{cccc}
  \frac{ 1 }{ 0 }   & 1^2 - 7 \cdot 0^2 = 1 &     \mbox{digit}  &  2  \\  
  \frac{ 2 }{ 1 }   & 2^2 - 7 \cdot 1^2 = -3 &     \mbox{digit}  &  1  \\  
  \frac{ 3 }{ 1 }   & 3^2 - 7 \cdot 1^2 = 2 &     \mbox{digit}  &  1  \\  
  \frac{ 5 }{ 2 }   & 5^2 - 7 \cdot 2^2 = -3 &     \mbox{digit}  &  1  \\  
  \frac{ 8 }{ 3 }   & 8^2 - 7 \cdot 3^2 = 1 &     \mbox{digit}  &  4  \\  
 \end{array}
 $$

==========================================================================

Here's a good one, not amazingly hard. Show that the modified Pell equation $x^2 - 221y^2 = -1$ has no solutions in integers $x,y$.

$$  \sqrt { 221} = 14 +     \frac{  \sqrt {221} - 14 }{ 1 }  $$ 
 $$    \frac{ 1 }{   \sqrt {221} - 14 }  =  \frac{    \sqrt {221} + 14 }{25 } = 1 +  \frac{    \sqrt {221} - 11 }{25 } $$ 
 $$    \frac{ 25 }{   \sqrt {221} - 11 }  =  \frac{    \sqrt {221} + 11 }{4 } = 6 +  \frac{    \sqrt {221} - 13 }{4 } $$ 
 $$    \frac{ 4 }{   \sqrt {221} - 13 }  =  \frac{    \sqrt {221} + 13 }{13 } = 2 +  \frac{    \sqrt {221} - 13 }{13 } $$ 
 $$    \frac{ 13 }{   \sqrt {221} - 13 }  =  \frac{    \sqrt {221} + 13 }{4 } = 6 +  \frac{    \sqrt {221} - 11 }{4 } $$ 
 $$    \frac{ 4 }{   \sqrt {221} - 11 }  =  \frac{    \sqrt {221} + 11 }{25 } = 1 +  \frac{    \sqrt {221} - 14 }{25 } $$ 
 $$    \frac{ 25 }{   \sqrt {221} - 14 }  =  \frac{    \sqrt {221} + 14 }{1 } = 28 +  \frac{    \sqrt {221} - 14 }{1 } $$

Simple continued fraction tableau:
 $$ 
 \begin{array}{cccccccccccccccccc}
 & & 14 & & 1 & & 6 & & 2 & & 6 & & 1 & & 28 & \\ 
 \\ 
  \frac{ 0 }{ 1 }   &   \frac{ 1 }{ 0 }   & &   \frac{ 14 }{ 1 }   & &   \frac{ 15 }{ 1 }   & &   \frac{ 104 }{ 7 }   & &   \frac{ 223 }{ 15 }   & &   \frac{ 1442 }{ 97 }   & &   \frac{ 1665 }{ 112 }    \\ 
  \\ 
 & 1 & & -25 & & 4 & & -13 & & 4 & & -25 & & 1
 \end{array}
 $$

$$ 
 \begin{array}{cccc}
  \frac{ 1 }{ 0 }   & 1^2 - 221 \cdot 0^2 = 1 &     \mbox{digit}  &  14  \\  
  \frac{ 14 }{ 1 }   & 14^2 - 221 \cdot 1^2 = -25 &     \mbox{digit}  &  1  \\  
  \frac{ 15 }{ 1 }   & 15^2 - 221 \cdot 1^2 = 4 &     \mbox{digit}  &  6  \\  
  \frac{ 104 }{ 7 }   & 104^2 - 221 \cdot 7^2 = -13 &     \mbox{digit}  &  2  \\  
  \frac{ 223 }{ 15 }   & 223^2 - 221 \cdot 15^2 = 4 &     \mbox{digit}  &  6  \\  
  \frac{ 1442 }{ 97 }   & 1442^2 - 221 \cdot 97^2 = -25 &     \mbox{digit}  &  1  \\  
  \frac{ 1665 }{ 112 }   & 1665^2 - 221 \cdot 112^2 = 1 &     \mbox{digit}  &  28  \\  
 \end{array}
 $$